# SABRE Bargain Finder Max API

Tags: sabre

Why Sabre is returning not found in this request?

Address: https://api.havail.sabre.com/v3.2.0/shop/flights?mode=live&limit=50&offset=1&enabletagging=true

Here is the Request:

```
{
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
        "Target": "Production",
        "OriginDestinationInformation": [{
            "DepartureDateTime": "2017-10-04T00:00:00",
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "JFK"
            },
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "LAX"
            },
            "RPH": "1"
        }, {
            "DepartureDateTime": "2017-10-10T00:00:00",
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "LAX"
            },
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "JFK"
            },
            "RPH": "2"
        }],
        "POS": {
            "Source": [{
                "PseudoCityCode": "4OMI",
                "RequestorID": {
                    "CompanyName": {
                        "Code": "TN"
                    },
                    "ID": "REQ.ID",
                    "Type": "1"
                }
            }]
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "IntelliSellTransaction": {
                "RequestType": {
                    "Name": "50ITINS"
                }
            }
        },
        "TravelPreferences": {
            "ValidInterlineTicket": true,
            "CabinPref": [{
                "Cabin": "Y",
                "PreferLevel": "Preferred"
            }],
            "TPA_Extensions": {
                "TripType": {
                    "Value": "Return"
                }
            }
        },
        "TravelerInfoSummary": {
            "SpecificPTC_Indicator": false,
            "SeatsRequested": [1],
            "AirTravelerAvail": [{
                "PassengerTypeQuantity": [{
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Code": "ADT",
                    "Changeable": false
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

The response received from the API is always same as below:

```
{
    "status": "Complete",
    "reportingSystem": "RAF",
    "timeStamp": "2017-09-01T21:00:14+00:00",
    "type": "Application",
    "errorCode": "WARN.RAF.APPLICATION",
    "instance": "raf-darhlp012-9080",
    "message": "{\"OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS\":{\"PricedItinCount\":0,\"BrandedOneWayItinCount\":0,\"SimpleOneWayItinCount\":0,\"DepartedItinCount\":0,\"SoldOutItinCount\":0,\"AvailableItinCount\":0,\"Version\":\"3.2.0\",\"Errors\":{\"Error\":[{\"Type\":\"WORKERTHREAD\",\"ShortText\":\"4666151528036279040\",\"Code\":\"TRANSACTIONID\",\"MessageClass\":\"I\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"SERVER\",\"ShortText\":\"27033\",\"Code\":\"TTFHLP689\",\"MessageClass\":\"I\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"DEFAULT\",\"ShortText\":\"17500\",\"Code\":\"RULEID\",\"MessageClass\":\"I\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"SERVER\",\"Code\":\"MSG\",\"MessageClass\":\"I\",\"content\":\"No Availability\"},{\"Type\":\"ERR\",\"ShortText\":\"No Availability\",\"Code\":\"NAV\",\"content\":\"\"}]}},\"Links\":[{\"rel\":\"self\",\"href\":\""},{\"rel\":\"linkTemplate\",\"href\":\""},{\"rel\":\"tagLookupLinkTemplate\",\"href\":\},{\"rel\":\"paginatedRequestLinkTemplate\",\"href\":\}]}"
}
```

With different dates and itineraries, the response is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user is probably not active for consuming this service.

Comment: But, in contact with SABRE, the sallers said that the credentials are the same as CERT environment. That´s right?

Comment: Thank you, that´s right. The sales area was wrong. The SABRE suport confirmed today that the user is not active for consuming this service.